# I am trying to extract the emailController and the passwordController but I keep getting an error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, extract-method

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/common_widgets/form_submit_button.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/services/auth.dart';

enum EmailSignInFormType{signIn,register}

class EmailSignInForm extends StatefulWidget {
  EmailSignInForm({@required this.auth});
  final AuthBase auth;


  @override
  _EmailSignInFormState createState() => _EmailSignInFormState();
}

class _EmailSignInFormState extends State<EmailSignInForm> {

 final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
 final TextEditingController _passwordController =TextEditingController();

 String get _email=>_emailController.text;
 String get _password=> _passwordController.text;

 EmailSignInFormType _formType = EmailSignInFormType.signIn;

 void _submit() async {
   try {
     if (_formType == EmailSignInFormType.signIn) {
       await widget.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
     } else {
       await widget.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
     }
   } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
   }
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
 }

  void _toggleFormType(){
   setState(() {
    _formType = _formType == EmailSignInFormType.signIn?
        EmailSignInFormType.register: EmailSignInFormType.signIn;
   });
  }

  List<Widget> _buildChildren() {
    final primaryText = _formType == EmailSignInFormType.signIn ? 'Sign in' : 'Create account';
    final secondaryText = _formType == EmailSignInFormType.signIn
        ? 'Need an account? Register'
        : 'Have an account? Sign in';
    return [
      TextField(
        controller: _emailController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Email',
          hintText: 'test@test.com',
        ),
        autocorrect: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
      TextField(
        controller: _passwordController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Password',
        ),
        obscureText: true,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
      FormSubmitButton(
        text: primaryText,
        onPressed: _submit,
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
    FlatButton(
      child: Text(secondaryText),
      onPressed: _toggleFormType,
    ),
   ];

 }





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: _buildChildren(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I'm working on customizing my text field for my  email and password.When I go to extract the method from emailController and  passwordController.I receive an error saying "the end of the selection contains characters that do not belong to the statement.I checked everything and the code seems correct to me but its still not working can you please help me out.I imported the all of the code into a code snippet so that you could see all of the code on the page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's that, but you do have some random `+` in the end of line `47`

Secondly, I assume you wanted to return `Column` with `TextField`s and other widgets in it, but instead there's bunch of widgets separated with commas.

So possibly you've lost the top part of your code

Comment: Yes, that's the reason of error.

Comment: @FaizanAhmad Can you please show me how to fix the error I am still not comprehending how to fix it.I under stand that I need to get rid of the commas but what do I need to replace them with?

Comment: Commas are fine, he just needed to put all of his widgets in a Column

Comment: But I suppose you have different code and possibly different issue

Comment: @SzymonKowaliński I imported all of the code into a code snippet so you can see what I am working with.Could you please show me how to put all of the columns together so  I can get passed this roadblock.

Comment: Where's the snippet?

Comment: @SzymonKowaliński the code snippet is in the code snippet box at the top of the page